# "strcpy()" se comportando estranhamente dependendo de como se coloca no "if"

Tags: c, string

O que está ocorrendo aqui?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void escolha_simb(char *jog1, char *jog2)   //** escolhe quem vai ser x ou o
{
        char esc;

        while (1) {
                printf("\njogador 1, escolha X ou O \n");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c",&esc);
                if (esc == 'x')
                {
                        strcpy(jog2,"O");
                        strcpy(jog1,"X");

                        break;
                }
                else if (esc == 'o')
                {
                        strcpy(jog2,"X");
                        strcpy(jog1,"O");

                        break;
                }
        }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        char jog1=0,jog2=0;
        printf("jog1: %c jog2: %c",jog1,jog2 );
        escolha_simb(&jog1,&jog2);
        printf("depois\njog1: %c jog2: %c",jog1,jog2 );
        return 0;
}
```

Saida, caso escolha X:

> ```
> jog1:   jog2:
> jogador 1, escolha X ou O
> x
> depois
> jog1: X jog2: O
> ```

porém se inverter os `strcpy()`:

```
 if (esc == 'x')
                {
                        strcpy(jog1,"X");
                        strcpy(jog2,"O");


                        break;
                }
                else if (esc == 'o')
                {
                        strcpy(jog1,"O");
                        strcpy(jog2,"X");


                        break;
                }
```

saída, caso escolha X :

> ```
> jog1:   jog2:
> jogador 1, escolha X ou O
> x
> depois
> jog1:   jog2: O
> ```

por que `jog1` fica nulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está misturando `char` com *string*, são coisas diferentes. Quando usa `char` não deve nem usar `strcpy()`, nem atribuir usando aspas duplas que se referem à *strings*. Não dará problema sempre, mas a forma codificada não é correta, assim é mais correto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void escolha_simb(char *jog1, char *jog2) {
    while (1) {
        printf("\njogador 1, escolha X ou O \n");
        char esc;
        scanf("%c", &esc);
        if (esc == 'x') {
            *jog2 = 'X';
            *jog1 = 'O';
            break;
        }
        else if (esc == 'o') {
            *jog2 = 'O';
            *jog1 = 'X';
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char jog1 = 0, jog2 = 0;
    printf("jog1: %c jog2: %c", jog1, jog2);
    escolha_simb(&jog1, &jog2);
    printf("depois\njog1: %c jog2: %c", jog1, jog2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EFhqAk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mrdwmhlv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Char.c).

Provavelmente tem maneiras mais performáticas de realizar isto, mas precisaria testar.

Comment: entendi, vou usar seu metodo. mas mesmo assim, é aleatorio ele dar nulo? porque apenas fazendo uma inversão deles dá o resultado correto?

Comment: Não diria aleatório, mas é difícil saber quando acontece. Em C você precisa entender tudo o que se passa na memória, cada byte que é colocando em cada lugar, entender cada detalhes do funcionamento a linguagem. Ela é uma linguagem flexível e poderosa, e pode dar uma boa noção do funcionamento real de códigos, mas não é simples para uso na maioria das aplicações ou quem naõ quer se aprofundar.