# Atribuição em declaração de variáveis em C

Tags: c, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

É necessário atribuir um valor para uma variável em C assim que declaramos a mesma? Pergunto porque um programador já idoso me disse que se faz necessário, pois, caso não declaremos de inicio, o compilador poderia atribuir qualquer valor aleatório a ela. Segue a declaração seguindo a orientação do *senior programmer*:

```
int num = 0;
```

Segundo ele tem que ser desta forma sempre que se for declarar uma variável.
Minha pergunta é: Se faz mesmo necessário isso? Meu compilador não gera esse numero aleatório como ele diz. E se for necessário, como faço para variáveis do tipo caractere? Esta forma não seria para compiladores antigos?

Obs: Ele usa o turbo C. Tem 70 anos e todo dia programa. É uma lenda.

Comment: Não é necessário atribuir valor à variável imediatamente a seguir a declará-la.Contudo, temos sempre de atribuir um valor à variável antes de ser usada. Por exemplo, pode declarar a variável no inicio do seu código, e só atribuir valor imediatamente antes de usar a variável.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> É necessário atribuir um valor para uma variável em C assim que declaramos a mesma?

Não, isso fazia menos sentido no compiladores mais antigos do que agora. Os primeiros compiladores C obrigavam declarar a variável no começo da função antes de ter qualquer execução real, então se fosse obrigado atribuir um valor na declaração haveria uma execução (custo de processamento) que logo ali na frente seria desprezada e seu valor substituído por outro em uma nova atribuição, o que é ineficiente e contra a filosofia de C, então atribuir valor na declaração era em grande parte dos casos desincentivada.

Com o tempo os compiladores foram capazes de entender declaração só no momento que a variável é necessária, e isto inclusive já está na especificação da linguagem desde 1999, então qualquer compilador que não atende uma especificação de 20 anos atrás é um compilador podre e nem deveria ser considerado C mais.

Infelizmente algumas pessoas ensinam programar desta forma, ou porque não conseguem fazer diferente do que aprenderam, só seguem receita de bolo, ou porque acreditam no mito que tem compilador que não aceita essa forma (sim, tem, mas novamente ele não pode ser considerado C e a maioria dos códigos nunca serão compilados por um compilador assim, e a solução para o caso se for mesmo necessário compilar esse código em um compilador defasado é usar uma ferramenta que processa esse código antes de passar para o compilador, assim não obriga o código ser pior por uma exceção (a não ser que não seja exceção, tem que olhar o caso concreto), mas as pessoas não costumam se comportar como engenheiros e não procuram soluções adequadas, apenas seguem o fluxo de alguém que teve uma ideia ruim um dia).

Mas ainda em compiladores modernos pode ter algum caso menos comum de que a declaração deva ser feita antes do seu valor ser atribuído e ainda vale a filosofia de máxima eficiência, portanto C não obriga atribuir um valor na declaração. Um exemplo típico é se essa variável receberá uma entrada de dados externa, onde claramente haverá uma atribuição, então para que atribuir um valor que será descartado antes do seu uso? Isso vale para qualquer função que receberá a variável como parâmetro por referência só para preenchê-la. E pode ter outros casos.

O programador experiente que lhe falou isso está certo para compiladores modernos na maioria dos casos, mas talvez ele não disse da forma mais correta, ou você não entendeu bem o que ele disse. Você deve sempre atribuir um valor para a variável antes de usá-la. Não precisa ser na declaração, mas em algum momento entre a declaração e o primeiro acesso a esse valor, pode inclusive ser na própria declaração, e hoje na esmagadora maioria dos casos é o local ideal para fazer isto (leia uma das exceções mais importantes no parágrafo anterior).

Se você falhar nisso acessará lixo que está na memória, e o pior que pode acontecer com você é funcionar, porque achará que está certo. Alguns casos o lixo pode ser exatamente o que você espera e parecer que está certo, mas em outros casos não será assim. C é provavelmente a linguagem de "alto nível" onde essa máxima mais vale:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Uma forma de evitar que isto aconteça é atribuir logo na declaração, mas não faça isso com regra geral única. É o comportamento padrão, até que tenha um motivo para fazer diferente.

Se você apender isso como receita de bolo está aprendendo errado, se entender a real motivação e aí tomar decisão dependendo do caso concreto que está fazendo, aí  tornou-se um programador de verdade. E se for melhorando essa habilidade e procurar sempre soluções criativas e sensatas para os problemas se tornará um engenheiro.

> Meu compilador não gera esse numero aleatório como ele diz

Isso me preocupa, precisa entender o que é esse "numéro aleatório" para poder tomar decisões corretas (veja comentário abaixo).

> Esta forma não seria para compiladores antigos?

Como eu disse, não, pelo contrário, em compiladores antigos fazia até mais sentido que hoje não atribuir valores durante a declaração em boa parte dos casos.

> E se for necessário, como faço para variáveis do tipo caractere?

Da mesma forma que outros tipos, não tem diferença:

```
char c = 'x';
```

Ajudou? Acho que não porque depende do contexto. Tem vários motivos para fazer de um jeito ou de outro.

Agora sem declarar e faz sentido (aqui tem contexto):

```
char c;
scanf("%c", c);
```

Tem um [exemplo com contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/346041/101).

Quer fazer isso como *string*?

```
char texto[] = "teste";
```

Um exemplo de absurdo de atribuição em declaração sem necessidade:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
//mais código aqui
fp = fopen("Emails.txt", "rt");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/VariableAssign.c).

Só uma coisa é pior que isto, é não ter código algum entre a declaração e a real inicialização. Não por performance, mas por não fazer sentido deixar em linhas separadas por critério algum.

Veja mais em:

- [Qual a forma correta de se declarar um string em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236175/101)
- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101)
- [Por que uma atribuição de string em C não funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136628/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre atribuir e comparar variáveis strings com função ou com operador de atribuição e comparação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80074/101)

Comment: Numero aleatorio: Segundo a logica dele, caso eu declare uma variavel e não atribua um valor inicial a ela, e se eu der um print na mesma, a saida seria qualquer numero. Ate onde eu sei, e assim ocorre no meu compilador, a saida é 0. Mas segundo ele a saida poderia ser qualquer numero inteiro "escolhido aleatoriamente " pelo compilador. Na pratica ja vi que isso não ocorre. Só queria saber se isso ocorria nos primordios da linguagem.

Comment: O número não é aleatório, é apenas indeterminado, não tem nada de aleatório, e muito menos é escolhido pelo compilador, alias, o compilador tem zero influência nisso. Será um número que está na memória naquele momento na posição onde aquela variável se refere naquela execução. Tem mais a ver com o sistema operacional, e em algumas arquiteturas sob algumas configurações tem grande chance em um exemplo muito básico que o valor seja o mesmo que terminou na última execução desse código, se ele for chamado logo em seguida. Nada aleatório.

Answer (score 0):

É assim é recomendavel que você inicialize as variaveis com algum valor para não correr riscos... No c geralmente são inicializadas as variaveis numericas com 0 mas as vezes ele pega um numero aleatório da RAM para inicializar essa variavel

Para variaveis do tipo char elas funcinam de maneira diferente das numericas essas não e necessario inicializaçao pois elas criam alocações de memoria consoante o tamnho que lhes atribui

Por exemplo:

`char var[10];`

Neste exemplo a variavel char vai ocupar o espaco de 10 caracteres elas levam sempre um caracter de escape no fim para saberem quando a string termina

Mas no caso de fazeres:

`var[]="Fulano";`

ela só vai ocupar o espaço de 7 caracteres (6 da palavra Fulano e mais 1 do caracter de escape \0) [Não precisas colocar o caracter de escape]

E nesse caso a variavel vai ser equivalente a:

`char var[7] = "Fulano";`

Mas como não declaramos a variavel com 7 e sim com 10 carcteres o resto dos caracteres são preenchidos com NULL

Espero que tenha respondido há tua duvida :)